# Is it possible to send a shell command from a registry value

Tags: registry

I have a wireless remote for windows. For one of the buttons it will open windows media player. The registry entry that controls this is

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\16]
"Association"=".cda"
```

I removed changed `"Association"=".cda"` to `"Association"=""` to disable the button.

I would like to however associate this button with closing an exe called mph-hc64.exe instead. Is it possible to put a shell command as the value instead? I see another appkey to open the calculator is

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18]
"ShellExecute"="calc.exe"
```

which I am guessing is utilizing a shell command to start calc.exe. So could something like a `SendMessage() WM_CLOSE` of sort be used to close calc.exe or any other process running for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ended up using nircmd to handle the issue. I changed the registry key value to
`"ShellExecute"="C:\\Program Files\\nircmd.exe closeprocess mpc-hc64.exe"`

Problem solved